# Prove 2 groups made up of rational numbers are isomorphic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

Given groups are -

$Q*$ multiplicative group of non zero rational numbers

$G$ defined as $G= \{ x : x\in\mathbb{Q}|x\neq1\}$;
$a*b=a+b-ab$

Identity in $G$ is $0$ and inverse of any element $a$ is $−a/(1-a)$

How do I go about it?

Comment: What is the group structure on $G$?

Comment: $a*b=a+b-ab$, I have added in question

Comment: How about showing some of your own work first? Have you worked out what the identity is in G? Have you tried doing some multiplication in G? Computing inverses?

Comment: Identity in $G$ is 0 and inverse of any element $a$ is $-a/(1+a)$. Questions I have encountered till now could be proved either by constructing product table or showing both are cyclic. Here I am clueless, how to make map which is bijective or anything

Comment: I don't think that is the inverse.  If nothing else, that expression is not defined for $a=-1$.

Comment: $−a/(1−a)$ would be inverse for $a$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are looking for a bijection $f: G \to  \Bbb Q^\times$ such that $f(a * b)=f(a)f(b)$ for all $a,b$. The first thing to do is look at "special" elements of $\Bbb Q$.

As you correctly noted, $0$ is the identity element in $G$, so we must have $f(0)=1$.

Another special element of $\Bbb Q$ is $-1$: it is the only element of order $2$. So we must have $f(2) = -1$ since $2$ is the only element of order $2$ in $G$.

This could be enough for a first guess, but let's make a final observation. If we extend the operation of $G$ to all the rational numbers (using the same formula), we see that $1*a=1$. That is, $1$ behaves with $*$ like $0$ does with ordinary multiplication in $\Bbb Q$. That is just a hint that looking for an $f:\Bbb Q \to \Bbb Q$ such that $f(1)=0$ might not be a bad idea.

If you plot the three above points $(a,f(a))$ for $a\in\{0,1,2\}$, you'll see that they lie on the same line $y=1-x$. So $f(x)=1-x$ is our first guess. And it works, as you can easily verify that it respects the group operation and it is clearly a bijection between $G$ and $\Bbb Q^\times$.

Answer (score 1):

The map $f\colon x\mapsto \frac{x-1}x$ is a group isomorphism $\mathbb{Q}^\times\to G$

Proof: $f$ is bijective with inverse $y\mapsto\frac 1{1-y}$. We have to see that it is a group homomorphism. This is a straightforward calculation:
$$f(x)*f(y)=\frac{x-1}x+\frac{y-1}y-(\frac{x-1}x)(\frac{y-1}y) =\frac{(xy-y)+(xy-x)-(xy-y-x+1)}{xy} = f(xy)$$

Comment: Interesting solution! How did you come up with that formula? Also, you've got the sign of the inverse function wrong.

Comment: @posilon First I tried an approach of the form $x\mapsto 1+ax$ which should have yielded $x\mapsto 1-x$ (which you posted). Due to a stupid sign error, I fooled myself into thinking it didn't work. So I considered the projective space $P=\mathbb{Q}\cup\{\infty\}$. Both $\mathbb{Q}^\times$ and $G$ are algebraic group structures on $P-\{p,q\}$ with unit $e$, where $p,q,e = 0,\infty, 1$ in the first case and $p,q,e = \infty,1,0$ in the second case. Thus I tried the form $x\mapsto\frac{a+bx}{c+dx}$ (the automorphisms or $P$) with $0\mapsto \infty$, $\infty\mapsto 1$, $1\mapsto 0$